# UPDATE set 3 fields in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I set these 3 in one query so I wouldn't be spamming my database over and over

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `pool_worker` SET `total_round_shares`='$total' WHERE `username`='$key'");
mysql_query("UPDATE `pool_worker` SET `total_round_rejects`='$totalRejected' WHERE `username`='$key'");
mysql_query("UPDATE `pool_worker` SET `total_found`='$total' WHERE `username`='$key'");
```

I tried looking around I can't find anything could anyone help a MySQL rookie?

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `pool_worker` SET `total_round_shares`='$total', `total_round_rejects`='$totalRejected', `total_found`='$total' WHERE `username`='$key'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are updating data from the same table and with same condition in your `where` condition, you can easily merge them, as;

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `pool_worker` 
             SET `total_round_shares`='$total',
                 `total_round_rejects`='$totalRejected',
                 `total_found`='$total'
             WHERE `username`='$key'");
```